# Error using a defined function with expl3 inside the command \color

Tags: color, expl3, l3prop

In the following MWE my personal definition of `\marco_prop_get:nn` works unless it isn't inside the macro `\color`. The snippet is:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \marco_prop_get:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_get:cn  { l_marco_ #1 _collection_prop } { #2 }
 }
\color{ \marco_prop_get:nn { color } {my-title} } My~ Title
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

I am a little bit confused because the using of `\prop_get:Nn` works well.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_marco_color_collection_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_marco_color_collection_prop {my-title} {red}
\color{ \prop_get:Nn\l_marco_color_collection_prop {my-title} } My~ Title
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\def\foo{red}
\color{\foo}\foo

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \foo { blue }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\color{\foo}\foo

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_marco_color_collection_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_marco_color_collection_prop {my-title} {red}
\color{ \prop_get:Nn\l_marco_color_collection_prop {my-title} } My~ Title
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \marco_prop_get:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_get:cn  { l_marco_#1_collection_prop } { #2 }
 }
\exp_after:wN \color \exp_after:wN { \marco_prop_get:nn { color } {my-title} } My~ Title

%\color {  \marco_prop_get:nn { color } {my-title} } My~ Title
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Can you explain please why does my command fail without `\exp_after:wN`.

Please note I am using the svn version of expl3.

Comment: Just a thought: wouldn't `\exp_args:No` a) be easier to read and b) be more “`expl3`-like” instead of `\exp_after:wN`?

Comment: @cgnieder: I can't test it now. Does it work?

Comment: Yes it works nicely :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would work with `color` but as far as I can see `xcolor` uses `\@onelevel@sanitize` to suppress expansion so the argument is safe for it to parse its more extensive color syntax.
So you need to make sure you do enough expansion before `\@onelevel@sanitize` uses `\meaning`. Hence the need for `\expandafter`.